spring cloud gateway, netflix eureka issue
I'm having issues with spring cloud gateway and netflix eureka, which were fine until recently.
The eureka server console log looks like this.
2024-09-02T00:25:38.368+09:00 ERROR 1088 --- [gateway-service-dev] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:469) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:257) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:202) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:990) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:628) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.9.jar:3.2.9]
    at com.oha.apigateway.OhaApiGatewayApplication.main(OhaApiGatewayApplication.java:16) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaApplicationInfoManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager]: Factory method 'eurekaApplicationInfoManager' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:376) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:373) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704) ~[spring-aop-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getInfo(<generated>) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-context-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager]: Factory method 'eurekaApplicationInfoManager' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null
    at java.base/java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2963) ~[na:na]
    at com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$Builder.setStatusPageUrl(InstanceInfo.java:623) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory.create(InstanceInfoFactory.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaApplicationInfoManager(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:331) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 31 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1

Spring cloud gateway also fails for the same reason

Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null

I tried a few things but couldn't solve it.

Upgrading springboot and cloud versions


springboot 3.2.x or 3.3.x
cloud 2023.0.3


Ways to comment on this posts
(1)
(2)

I've attached a link for a demo.
Github Eureka Demo

Feel free to open an issue in the Spring Cloud Netflix GitHub repository and link your sample there  - it will get into the team's triage queue then.

Is there any solution for this?
